# How many max no of API tokens be generated and when the maximum number is reached how to handle that behaviour?

Tags: api, azure-active-directory, access-token, signing, refresh-token

API Token generated from Sign In.
When I try to regenerate a token I see the previous one is still valid so my concern is how many maximum number of tokens can be generated and used simultaneously?

Second, when the maximum number is reached does it invalidate the oldest token or does it return an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default lifetime of an access token is variable. When issued, **an access token's default lifetime is assigned a random value ranging between 60-90 minutes (75 minutes on average)**. The variation improves service resilience by spreading access token demand over a **period of 60 to 90 minutes**, which prevents hourly spikes in traffic to Azure AD.

On workaround **there is no this limit for generating access token.** For the related Azure AD service limits, refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits#active-directory-limits)

You can adjust the lifetime of an access token to control how often the client application expires the application session, and how often it requires the user to re-authenticate (either silently or interactively). Customers that wish to override default access token lifetime variation can set a static default access token lifetime by using [**Configurable token lifetime (CTL)**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes).

**Note: As of January 30, 2021 you can not configure refresh and session token lifetimes. Azure Active Directory no longer honors refresh and session token configuration in existing policies. New tokens issued after existing tokens have expired**

if you are using [MSAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-overview), **you don't have to test this expiry because it is handled by MSAL. So you can only ensure when refresh token expires**, you handle the authenticating the user again.

For more details refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#access-token-lifetime):